# Remove formatting when using ref in latex

Tags: latex

I have a section defined like this:

```
\section*{\huge Summary}
\label{chap:summary}
```

And then I use a \ref to it

```
\nameref{chap:summary}
```

But the reference also takes the \huge format. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should refrain from adding font selections as part of your section title. Instead, rely on packages to manage your formatting. Below I've used [`secsty`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sectsty) to adjust the section font; other options also exist:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{sectsty,nameref}
\sectionfont{\huge}
\begin{document}
\section*{Summary}\label{chap:summary}
See section \nameref{chap:summary}.
\end{document}
```